# Conversión de decimal a entero en python

Tags: python-2.7, script

Tengo el siguiente script en python:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse("/var/www/zabbix/SE_SAPASE.xml")
data = doc.getElementsByTagName("data")[0]
print (data.firstChild.data)
```

El resultado me lo arroja en decimal, lo que deseo es convertir el resultado a entero e imprimirlo, hasta ahora estoy comenzando con este tema de scripts
cualquier aporte me viene bastante bien.

Comment: Lo he resuelto hace un momento solo era añadir a la cadena el valor float()            print (int(float(data.firstChild.data)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo haz:

```
print ( int( float(data.firstChild.data) ) )
```

Comment: Por qué? Responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, si corriges eso te quito el -1

Comment: he realizado lo que me has sugerido pero al añadirle me sale el siguiente error:  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10